# Execution order of onSubscribe(), map() and flatMap()

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

In a simple demo program I compared the output of `Mono.just().map().subscribe()` and `Mono.just().flatMap().subscribe()`, to my surprise `map()` is executed after `onSubscribe()` but `flatMap()` is before.

The program:

```java
    public static void main(@Nonnull String[] args) {
        // 1. Case with map()
        Mono.just(1).map(number -> {
            System.out.printf("[%s] mapping:%d%n", threadName(), number);
            return number * 10;

        }).subscribe(buildSubscriber());

        // 2. Case with flatMap()
        System.out.println();
        Mono.just(1).flatMap(number -> {
            System.out.printf("[%s] flat-mapping:%d%n", threadName(), number);
            return Mono.just(number * 10);

        }).subscribe(buildSubscriber());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ReactiveStreamsSubscriberImplementation")
    @Nonnull
    private static Subscriber<Integer> buildSubscriber() {
        return new Subscriber<>() {
            private Subscription subscription;

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                System.out.printf("[%s] onSubscribe%n", threadName());
                this.subscription = subscription;
                subscription.request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer item) {
                System.out.printf("[%s] onNext:%s%n", threadName(), item);
                subscription.request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.printf("[%s] onError:%s%n", threadName(), throwable);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.printf("[%s] onComplete%n", threadName());
            }
        };
    }

    @Nonnull
    private static String threadName() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }
```

The output:

```
[main] onSubscribe
[main] mapping:1
[main] onNext:10
[main] onComplete

[main] flat-mapping:1
[main] onSubscribe
[main] onNext:10
[main] onComplete
```

In the output of the first case `onSubscribe` is before `mapping:1`. It's conceivable that the subscriber made a request for one event and then the publisher produced one, and then this very event went through the transformation and other operations if any.

In the output of the second case `flat-mapping:1` comes first, which means `onSubscribe()` is not yet called but the event is emitted already. The [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) says that `map()` is implemented [by applying a synchronous function](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), and `flatMap()` [transforms asynchronously](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-). What we witness here is that everything happens in the `main`  thread.

Things seem in contradiction, neither `flatMap()` is performed asynchronously, nor the publisher emits on subscriber's demand, so what's going on under the hood in reactor？